# How to find whether a value is occurring in sequence or time order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have given two dataframes below for you to test

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'time_1' :['2173-04-03 10:00:00','2173-04-03 10:15:00','2173-04-03 10:30:00','2173-04-03 10:45:00','2173-04-03 11:01:00','2173-04-04 12:00:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 06:30:00'],
'val' :[5,5,5,5,5,10,5,8,3,8,10]
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'time_1' :['2173-04-03 10:00:00','2173-04-03 10:15:00','2173-04-03 10:30:00','2173-04-03 10:45:00','2173-04-03 11:01:00','2173-04-04 12:00:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 06:30:00'],
'val' :[5,6,5,6,5,10,5,8,3,8,10]
 })
```

I am trying to find whether values from `val` column **are in sequence** (time order). I mean a value appears without break (ex: 5,5,5 is a sequence (time order) whereas 5,6,5,6 is example where sequence of 5 is broken). Can you help me find that?

This is what I tried something cumsum and duration but it doesn't work

```
df['time_1']= pd.to_datetime(df1['time_1'])
s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df.time_1-df.time_1.dt.normalize())
df['tdiff'] = 
df.groupby(df.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s)
df['t_d'] = df['tdiff'].dt.total_seconds()/3600
df['date'] = df['time_1'].dt.date
df.groupby(['val','date'],sort=False)['t_d'].agg({'cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index()
```

I expect my df_2 output to be something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a little too much overhead.  Stuff these steps into a one-line command:

1. Shift ["val"] one position left ...
2. ... compare that shifted sequence to ["val"] with <= ...
3. That gives you a sequence of Booleans; apply `all()` to that

The result of `all()` tells you whether they're in non-descending sequence.

Coding is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: In 2nd step, why do we have to use `<=`, if i am checking whether they are same, shouldn't it be just `=`? Just trying to learn

Comment: You asked to find whether they're in order, not whether they're the same.  Also, finding sequences of matching values has been solved many times on Stack Overflow, and you *should* have found those solutions without posting a new question.